# Importing in plain JS file

Tags: javascript, import, ramda.js

I am trying to keep my files as basic as possible.
Therefore in my html file I have:

```html
<script src="js/binarytree_standardgrid_script.js"></script>
```

and then inside my `binarytree_standardgrid_script.js` file I would like to use: `Ramda.js`

How do I "import" `Ramda.js` or "include" `Ramda.js` without using node? or do I really neeed to use node?

And then I have another file called `BinaryTree.js`

The file structure is

```
    ./index.html 
    ./algorithms/BinaryTree.js
    ./js/binarytree_standardgrid_script.js
```

and inside the html file I call the `binarytree_standardgrid_script.js` by:

and inside that script I would like to be able to use `BinaryTree.js` and then also Ramda Library.

How can I do that in Javascript? Do I really need to use node?

Comment: You can just add `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>` before your own script, as mentioned on their website. https://ramdajs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution:

Just put the scripts on the html page:

```
<script src="algorithms/BinaryTree.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/binarytree_standardgrid_script.js"></script>
```

The classes and functions will then be available in the script file as long as it is not inside a function.

Comment: It looks like the website didn't get updated recently.  The current version is 0.26.1: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js.